# Typescript utility method Extract false from boolean returns false

Tags: typescript

Calling the typescript utility type `Extract<Type, Union>` like this:

```
type t = Extract<boolean, false> // false
```

returns `false`

Shouldn't this be `never` since the Extract implementation is :

```
Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
```

and since boolean does not extend false :

```
boolean extends false ? true : never // never
```

Edit :

This is being discussed here :
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22596#issuecomment-373722622

Comment: "*and since boolean does not extend false*" the type system would be *quite poor* if it couldn't figure out if a value is one of the only two that will ever be in `boolean`. I do not see the value of an implementation which doesn't in some way represent `type boolean = true | false`

Comment: @VLAZ But if you create `type T2 = boolean extends false ? true : never`, and hover over it in an IDE with TS support, you can see it evaluates to never.

Comment: This is because of distributed conditional types. `boolean` is indeed `true| false`. Since `Extract` distributes over unions, `Extract<boolean, false> = Extract<true | false, false> = Extract<true , false> | Extract<false, false> = never | false = false`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. I see yes. But still, I'm not passing a union as the first parameter. I'm passing the type `boolean`.
From the docs : 'When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type'

Comment: `boolean` is a union of `true | false`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir interesting, but not the behavior I expected tbh.

Comment: @ShamPooSham you'd prefer if `boolean` was a whole unit and never evaluated as a union of `true` and `false`?

Comment: @VLAZ No, I'd expect this evaluation: `Extract<boolean, false>` => `Extract<true | false, false>` => `(true | false) extends false ? (true | false) : never` => `never`

Comment: @ShamPooSham Distributive conditionals are quite useful. I don't know how you'd implement some types without them.

Comment: @vera. I'm not really saying distributive conditionals are bad, just that they didn't follow my expectations. I can see that they're useful.